# QtQuick 1.1 Image Rounded Corners

Tags: qml, qt4, qt-quick, qqmlcomponent

I am limited to using QtQuick 1.1 (Qt 4.8) , and so have no access to the GraphicalEffects library.  Also I am not able to use any C++ and so the solution has to be pure QML (frustrating limitations - i know!).

I need to be able to display an image with rounded corners, but have so far been unable to. I have tried wrapping the image inside a clipped Rectangle with a radius but the clip doesn't work!  Also thought about applying a border colour on a rectangle over the top but the background can be a gradient or image and so cannot have a solid color border.

Is this possible in QtQuick 1.1 (Qt 4.8)?  I would appreciate some suggestions.